# Making multiple calling options show when clicking phone number link in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I've used a UITextView and set its dataDetectorTypes to detect phone numbers. The thing is, when I click on phone link, I get prompted with an alert to make the call with regular Phone app. I would like to get prompted with every option available in the device (say, Skype, Viber, whatever app that allows making calls). If you could help me, I  would greatly appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

To make phone calls via **default Phone app**

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:phoneNoStr];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

To make calls via **Skype** you can use this code found from [skype docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745885(v=office.15).aspx#How)

```
BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
if(installed)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype"]];
}
```

To make calls via **facetime** you can use use similar url scheme

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://+123456789"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

**Viber** does not support URL scheme for now. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, asking to a friend in my company revealed that, unlike Android, there isn't anything in iOS that automatically detects your calling apps to show them as options to make the call, you would have to do it yourself programatically, which I think is the approach you followed in this example. Anyway, my problem was solved since I thought it was some sort of configuration issue that wasn't allowing me to detect the calling apps in the iPhone, but now I know it's something considered as normal in iOS. My apologies if I didn't make that clear in my question.

Comment: Yes your friend is correct . There is nothing in iOS that allows you to detect all calling apps. Happy coding!!